# how to use mpdf and pjax in Yii2 view?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, mpdf, pjax

I am using pjax form in this i have print button and submit button like below.

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['name' => 'form', 'value' => 'submit']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Pdf', ['name' => 'form', 'value' => 'pdf']) ?>
```

I will capture both submit in controller like below

```
 public function actionRetail()
{
 $model = new Retail();
 if (Yii::$app->request->post('form') == 'submit') 
 {
    $model->saveRetail();
    $this->redirect("/Details");
}
if (Yii::$app->request->post('form') == 'pdf') 
{
    $mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('DetailsPdf'));
    $mpdf->Output('details.pdf','D');   
}
  return $this->render('View',['model'=>$model]);
}
```

In this form submit is working fine, but if whenever click pdf button instead of download pdf it's showing encoded data at same page like below.If i remove pjax it's working fine. Please help any one how to use mpdf in pjax view.

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <> /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x��[Msܸ�Y���C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable pjax for pdf button. Just add 'data-pjax' => 0

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Pdf', ['name' => 'form', 'value' => 'pdf', 'data-pjax' => 0]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define a new \Mpdf\Mpdf document using utf-8 fonts
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8']);
```

[view this link](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/issues/24)